# Sending large amount of POST data, in xampp ok, in plesk not ok

Tags: php, post, kohana, plesk

I have developed a project with `KOHANA` Framework and a form send a large amount of data via `POST`. The problem is that in my local environment (`XAMPP`) I see all my data, when I type `print_r($_POST)`, but in live environment (`Plesk`) I don't see all. I increased the `max_input_vars` in to 25000, the `post_max_size` in to 256M and I left the memory limit in the default of `Plesk`. One thing, that I found strange, was that in NET tab in Firebug console, I see all the data of the `$_POST`. Can someone help me?

Comment: 2 clarifications: [A} what do you mean with "large amount of data" - mb in size? number of form fields? mixed content (text + images for example)? and [B] what do you mean you dont see them all in live enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Kohana unsets `$_POST`. You should try to use `$this->request->post()`

[Post API reference](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request#post)